# Arduino IDE does not find msg header

Tags: ros, arduino, msg, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to learn rosserial_arduino. I've worked through the tutorials and am now going back and walking through them with my own code. My initial test code will use rosserial_arduino to turn 8 LEDs on and off. I've created the package (arduino) and a custom message called 8Leds.msg. I added the lines per the tutorials to package.xml and CMakeLists.txt. I source my files and run catkin_make. Everything seems to compile properly and the 8Leds.h file is created in devel/include/arduino. However, when I try to compile the sketch for the arduino I get this error:

In file included from light_8_leds_test.ino:2:0:
/home/jcicolani/catkin_ws/devel/include/arduino/8Leds.h:42:18: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

I don't get it. It's even showing the exact path and file name.

Thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189914/arduino-ide-does-not-find-msg-header/) by [jcicolani](https://answers.ros.org/users/20002/jcicolani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to run the following again everytime you changed/added msg files in your workspace:

```
  cd <sketchbook>/libraries
  rm -rf ros_lib
  rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .
```

See: http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Arduino%20IDE%20Setup#Install_ros_lib_into_the_Arduino_Environment

Note that your arduino code needs to be compiled against the headers in your /libraries folder, not against those in your catkin workspace....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Navigate to your sketchbook folder and try to compile the libraries for arduino again. Simply do again the following steps (like in this tutorial).

```
cd <sketchbook>/libraries    
rm -rf   ros_lib   
rosrun rosserial_arduino   make_libraries.py .
```

You have created the msg files for ROS but they must be compiled for Arduino too. Running the above command you should get them compiled

Regards

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-08-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcicolani](https://answers.ros.org/users/20002/jcicolani/) on 2014-08-13**:
I ran the commands. However, I am now getting:
*** Warning: failed to generate libraries for the following packages: ***
map_msgs
arduino

All of the help I've seen in my Google and ROS Answers searches to date say to ignore the map_msgs (fine, not using it anyway) but there is nothing on troubleshooting what causes it or how to track down the problem for custom messages.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-08-13**:
ignore it.
I use without problems rosserial_arduino and I get always the message about map_msgs

**Comment by [jcicolani](https://answers.ros.org/users/20002/jcicolani/) on 2014-08-13**:
Map_msgs isn't the problem. It also failed to generate the libraries for my custom messages, which I need.

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-08-14**:
Do you mean, that after running the python-script again doesnt create any folder with your message definition in your ~/sketchbok/libraries ? You should see in ros_lib a new flder with the same name of your custom msg. Inside there are the .h files